# Request facebook permissions/login after ajax form validation (in ajax response)

Tags: ajax, facebook

It is working right now , but I have some feedback of user saying that the facebook popup is blocked by the browser

So what I am doing right now: I have a form that is being validated via ajax (making a call to a php page) , then if the response is successful, it ask for the user login/permissions. I assume that the popup is sometime blocked because the browser consider the ajax response not as an user action.

So my code looks like this :

```
$("#submit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(result){
            if(result==""){
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                   FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) { ... });
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                   FB.login(function (response) { ... });
                }
              }
            }
        }
     });
```

Any idea other than putting the facebook calls before the form validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax request as synchronous call. I don't like it though

btw, what kind of validation you are doing?

Comment: There is a lot of validations coming from a php library , that's why I don't want to try to do the same in js, and calling the php page in ajax instead. Synchronous ajax call is a good idea but I'm not sure I want to take the risk of freezing the page is the answer doesn't come immediatly.

Comment: If you cannot have without validation, you dont have other choice other than going with synchronous. Show some loader message before page freeze.

Comment: Or ask user to click again with good message (synchronous is better than this)